# Как узнать нажата ли правая кнопка мыши в pygame (python)?

Tags: python, pygame

```
import pygame as pg
while True:
    if pg.'правая кнопка мыши'.get_pressed()
        print('hi')
    else:
        print('bye')
```

Кто-то знает что надо вставить на место 'правая кнопка мыши' чтобы отследить её нажатие?
Я умею раюотать с клавиатурай, но не с мышью.
Спасибо за ответы!

Comment: `pygame.MOUSE_BUTTON_DOWN` — нет?

Comment: Это то да, но как обозначить правая это или левая кнопка мыши?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Определить, какая кнопка мыши нажата можно так:

```
for i in pg.event.get():
    if i.type == pg.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
        if i.button == 1:
            # События для левой кнопки мыши
        elif i.button == 2:
            # Для нажатия колесика
        elif i.button == 3:
            # Для правой кнопки мыши
```

Comment: А что делать если вылазит ошибка "pygame.error: video system not initialized" ?

Comment: @KREEPAR123, это всего лишь кусок кода. Я ничего не инициализировал. Вы должны все это сделать сами под нужды вашей программы. Как — это вы уж сами разбирайтесь.

Comment: Я понял - нужно написать `pg.init()` :)